# Impossible to hot reload on VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, ios-simulator, hot-reload

I'm trying to use hot reload on my Flutter project, but everytime I use it, I have this error:

> Hot reload received invalid response: {type: ReloadReport, success:
> false, notices: [{type: ReasonForCancelling, message: Error while
> starting Kernel isolate task}]}

I've tried every solution but none of these are working. Is there a fix for that? Thanks!

Comment: Which channel are you using? What is your operating system?

Answer (score -1):

**Please try one more time with the master channel.**

```
Upgrade to master and try again please:

flutter channel master
flutter upgrade --force
flutter doctor -v
```